# jQuery function to change td value with button inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a td text along with a button inside the td value.
I need to change the value when the user clicks the button, using jQuery functions.

So basically, I need to replace the text value of the td field.

`myValue.text("SomeValue");`   is changing the button value.

But I tried

`myValue.prev().text("someValue");` - to change the text value for the td, this is not working.

Any help please?

Adding the html td section :

bodyHtml +=''+ colHead[i-1] +
' ' + tags[i-1].firstChild.nodeValue +
'Toggle' +
' ';[image]

The ToggleValues() function is called on the Button click.
This function should change the value.

[Apologies, can't disclose the detailed function, due to Policy restrictions]

Comment: I recommend you always add a small code and html example when you ask a question.

Comment: Provide you HTML code so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).prev('span').text("New Text!!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Old Text</span>
      <button>Change it!!!</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would recommend to wrap the text inside a `span` or a `paragraph` tag.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this was helpful.
But as the button doesn't have siblings,
I used :  
$(this).parent('span').text("New Text!!!");

Answer (score 0):

with jquery use :  `$('td:has(button)').text()`

Comment: Provide more contents to support your answer, adding merely a code snippet doesn't seems to be a good answer.